# Percentage from difference in 2 ints

Tags: java

I want the percentage from the difference of 2 ints, the way packetloss is measured as an example, if     `int i= 10` and     `int t=4` the percentage is 60%.

Comment: Well, what did you try?

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: packetSend / packetReceive * 100

Comment: @user1794974:- So what is the problem? The logic is correct!

Comment: if packetSend is 100 and receive is 40 it shows 200%, should be 60% loss?

Comment: (total-received)/total*100=loss %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this.

```
((packetSend - packetReceive) * 100) / packetSend
```

Answer (score 6):

```
This is simple mathematics .

Int i=10;
Int t=4;

Float prctng=((i-t)/i )*100;
```

Answer (score 1):

So if i have well understood, you want the normalized distance between the two ints?

```
int a = 10;
int b = 4;
int distance = (int) 100 * (Math.abs(a-b)/Math.max(a,b)); // = 60
```